# Laravel check if image path string is image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing an image path as a GET paremeter when a link is clicked, but I need to check if this is an image for security reasons.

When I try this code, where `$fileName` is '15612.jpg':

```
$fileName = $_GET['fileName'];

$image = array('file' => File::get('unverified-images/'.$fileName));
$rules = array('file' => 'image');
$validator = Validator::make($image, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  Session::flash('error', 'Not an image'); 
  return Redirect::to('controlpanel');
}
```

All .jpg files I have tested give 'Not an image', but when I try with a .txt file it doesn't give an error, why is this? I'm guessing im doing something wrong, as the validator is supposed to fail when it's not an image, right?

I know the validator takes `Input::file()` instead of `File::get()`, but how can I use that if I'm not using a form?

Comment: You should use the http request instance of symfony, in your Laravel project. Never ever retrieve data with $_GET or $_POST. You can inject the request instance into your controllers as following :


`public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)`

Also you can register the illuminate\http\request class with the `use` statement.

Also you can do this in your controller :

`public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['image' => 'required|image']);
}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may be a case of avoiding the validator, and doing the check yourself, so you could do:

```
$allowedMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png','image/bmp','image/svg+xml'];
$contentType = mime_content_type('path/to/image');

if(! in_array($contentType, $allowedMimeTypes) ){
  Session::flash('error', 'Not an image'); 
  return Redirect::to('controlpanel');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Other way to check if it is an image is **getting the extension of the file** like this with php `explode` function:

**PHP**:

```
$imageExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'svg', 'svgz', 'cgm', 'djv', 'djvu', 'ico', 'ief','jpe', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'pnm', 'ppm', 'ras', 'rgb', 'tif', 'tiff', 'wbmp', 'xbm', 'xpm', 'xwd'];

$explodeImage = explode('.', 'path/image.jpg');
$extension = end($explodeImage);

if(in_array($extension, $imageExtensions))
{
    // Is image
}else
{
    // Is not image 
}
```

This work for me, regards!

Here you can find an **array of all file extensions**: [click here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raphael-riel/1253986/raw/cb34c92449dd5f0154123d7161c16b8d4440d138/file_extension_to_mimetype.php)

Comment: I know this is an older post, but what would 'image-url-here' be (example)?

Comment: It could be for example the $_POST['image'] getting the full url or just name of the image